# Can i custom Cortana to tell fairytale and speak slower?

Tags: window, cortana, assistant

This is first time i'm a father. And I'm a teacher in Kindergarten, too.
I know about Cortana a long time, but last day, I updated my laptop to Window 10 to use her, And my child so exciting.
But Cortana speak so fast, and they can not understand. My country don't use English (I live in Vietnam),  and they still learning. So, can I take Cortana to speaking with slower speed?

And, I find some tutorial in Google with key "How to custom Cortana command?". A lot video show me the way to Cortana turn off/ turn on computer. But if I want Cortana open "Jonny Jonny Yes Papa" song or kids song on my computer, or tell a fairytale, she not do that. And I have a question.
"Can I custom Cortana to ask her play fairytale or Music (most of them are .mp3 files) on my computer, with English name and use Voice to ask her? How does it work? and How can I do for this?. I'm still learning coding, it very hard for me but if I know where I can start to finding, it more easier and a lot things I can learn."
Sorry about my English grammar. And thanks you a lot!

Comment: If you want to teach Cortana to respond to "Read me a story", you want to add a [Cortana Voice Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could embed the text in ssml with a [modified prosody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/reference/ssml), which adjusts how quickly or slowly the text is read out loud. Your SSML would look something like this:

```
<speak version="1.0"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
    <prosody rate="slow">My spoken text goes here.</prosody>
</speak>
```

Using the SSML in your session.say() call would result in the text being spoken out loud.